# What's the mistake in a code written in PHP for push notification to be sent to iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, notifications, push-notification, pushwoosh

I've installed **php-pushwoosh** using **composer** at following location on my local machine :

```
/var/www/gomoob-php-pushwoosh
```

Now I want to send push notifications to **iPhone** through the PHP code.

So, I tried by myself and written PHP code in a file titled `sample.php` which is located at `/var/www/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/sample.php`. Following is the PHP code from file `sample.php`

Code Reference Link : [You can get the code reference here](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-PHPSample)

php-pushwoosh Installation reference Link : [php-pushwossh installation reference link](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

define('PW_AUTH', 'API TOKEN');
define('PW_APPLICATION', 'APPLICATION CODE');
define('PW_DEBUG', true);

function pwCall($method, $data) { 
    $url = 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/' . $method;
    $request = json_encode(['request' = $data]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (defined('PW_DEBUG') && PW_DEBUG) {
        print "[PW] request: $request\n";
        print "[PW] response: $response\n";
        print "[PW] info: " . print_r($info, true);
    }
}

pwCall('createMessage', array(
    'application' => PW_APPLICATION,
    'auth' => PW_AUTH,
    'notifications' => array(
            array(
                'send_date' => 'now',
                'content' => 'test',
                'data' => array('custom' => 'json data'),
                'link' => 'http://pushwoosh.com/'
            )
        )
    )
);
?>
```

After executing this code into browser by hitting the URL `localhost/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/sample.php` I'm getting blank page only, no errors, no warnings, no notices.

Why so? Can someone please correct the mistakes I'm making into my code by giving proper explanation and make my code workable?

If you need any further information regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

If you have any kind of suggestion, comment, answer, criticism, etc. you are most welcome. any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: put your error options into php.ini. setting them in the script is somehwat pointless, since they can only take effect if the script actually runs. any fatal parse errors and NOTHING will run, including the directives that'd let you actually see that parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in this line:

```
$request = json_encode(['request' = $data]);
                                  ^
```

It should obviously be:

```
$request = json_encode(['request' => $data]);
```

You didn't see any notice because the `display_errors` setting must be set outside of the script to catch parse errors such as this one.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help Jack. But I've put the display_errors setting inside of opening PHP tag i.e. <?php.

Comment: @user2839497 Yeah, but as I've mentioned in my answer, that must be defined *outside* the script, otherwise it can't catch parse errors.

Comment: By means of 'Outside' the script do you mean within a separate pairs of separate PHP tags?

Comment: @user2839497 No, I mean it should be defined in .htaccess or php.ini